# apn_on_rails not creating device

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails) and followed [this tutorial](http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail) to configure it

The problem is that my APN::device is not creating an object properly. From rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :020 > APN::Device.create(:token => "bd1545df 8c88041c eb7171c6 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx")
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `apn_devices` WHERE `apn_devices`.`token` = BINARY 'bd1545df 8c88041c eb7171c6 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<APN::Device id: nil, token: "bd1545df 8c88041c eb7171c6 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, last_registered_at: nil>
```

How can I fix this? I read that the problem might be from the token format. But I have tried
bd1545df 8c88041c eb7171c6 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx and also bd1545df8c88041ceb7171c6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened was that I was using the wrong device id. The device id has 8 blocks of 8 hex digits.

Also, if you try to create the same device twice the same problem appears. In rails console the devices registered can be deleted with the command:

```
APN::Device.destroy_all
```